# Rails console ignores attributes set with attr_accessor, and has_secure_password causes the password and the password_confirmation to be ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :name, :email
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

The problem is, in the Rails console, the attributes ***name, email, password, password_confirmation*** don't show up.

I suspect the first two are caused due to setting `attr_accessor :name, :email` and the latter two due to `has_secure_password`

But, when I call those attributes separately, they show up:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.2.1 :001 > u = User.new(name: "asd", email: "aedede@aece.com", password: "qweasd", password_confirmation: "qweasd")
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$a98/zxfH0zaT0Hh.xalVPOxwbJiXAkH17BiRg.sV4hw..."> 
2.2.1 :002 > u
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$a98/zxfH0zaT0Hh.xalVPOxwbJiXAkH17BiRg.sV4hw..."> 
2.2.1 :003 > u.name
 => "asd" 
2.2.1 :004 > u.email
 => "aedede@aece.com" 
2.2.1 :005 > u.password
 => "qweasd" 
2.2.1 :009 > u.save
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('aedede@aece.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["password_digest", "$2a$10$a98/zxfH0zaT0Hh.xalVPOxwbJiXAkH17BiRg.sV4hwFXp2jUiTnm"], ["created_at", "2015-06-10 02:42:22.437148"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-10 02:42:22.437148"]]
   (130.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.2.1 :010 > u
 => #<User id: 3, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2015-06-10 02:42:22", updated_at: "2015-06-10 02:42:22", password_digest: "$2a$10$a98/zxfH0zaT0Hh.xalVPOxwbJiXAkH17BiRg.sV4hw..."> 
2.2.1 :011 > u.name
 => "asd"
```

I've checked everything thoroughly and can't find what's causing this, any insights to what's actually happening under the hood would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: name and email are not the columns of user table?

Comment: how do I check whether they are?

Comment: `User.column_names` in rails console

Comment: 2.2.1 :012 > User.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest"]

Comment: remove attr_accessor name, email from user.rb and then try to instantiate object and check whether they are visible?

Comment: already done that, they are visible. That's why I'm asking why attr_accessor causes this?

Comment: look at my explanation regarding using `attr_accessor` for db columns in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683662/contact-form-error-on-seeding-and-error-messages-of-the-form-dont-work-properl/30683714#30683714

Answer (score -1):

`password` is not a column in your database `users`, and neither it should be. It is just an attribute. If you have used `has_secure_password`, and you have - Rails will automatically take the `password` you specified, encrypt it, and store a `password_digest` in the database. There would be not `password` column in the database.

In Rails 4.2, you don't need to write `attr_accessor` with your column names in your model. If you have defined them in migration, Rails will *automagically* create getter/setter and a bunch of other helping methods for you. So, you model `User` should look like following in Rails 4.2:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that clears up the password, but what about the name and email?

Comment: Yes, they are the columns in the database. As you have seen it through `User.column_names`. In Rails 4.2, you do not need to write `attr_accessor :name, :email` in your Model; if you have written them in migration, Rails will automatically create methods for you.

Comment: attr_accessor is different than attr_accessible...we don't have to define attr_accessible..but we can define attr_accessor..:)

Comment: Yes, we can use `attr_accessor` but we do not need to use it with database column in our model class. And if we do, we won't be able to access other helper methods that Rails creates for use. For example, you won't be able to do `User.find_by_email` or `User.find_by_email` if you used `attr_accessor :name, :email`.

Comment: @test For more information, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401768/how-does-activerecord-define-methods-compared-to-attr-accessor/14452353#14452353

Comment: **In Rails 4.2, you don't need to write attr_accessor with your column names in your model.** as you have mentioned I think that is for attr_accessible?

Comment: @test Yes, we don't need. And if we do, we won't be able to use the methods like `User.find_by_email`. Please take a look at the link in my last comment.

Comment: @test When you use `rails g scaffold User name:string email:string`, do you see those `attr_accessor` in your Model `User` class?

Comment: in rails version < 4 , the above command was creating `attr_accessible :name, :email` in model and not `attr_accessor :name, :email`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80134/discussion-between-arslan-ali-and-test).